# onUpgrade in sqlite database in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am developing a database application and I am stuck up at one place.

The scenario is: I have a database and I am maintaining the version of the database.
It is the same as that of the application version.

Now I am implementing the database in version 1. There are 3 tables getting created in version 1. In version 2, I am upgrading the database by adding one more table. Hence, the query is in the upgrade().

Now, what if the user installs version 2. The onUpgrade() will not get called because there is no database. Hence, the onCreate() will be called and the consequence will be it will create only 3 tables.

I was thinking to call the onUpgrade() explicitly in the onCreate(). But many developers on stackoverflow have suggested not to call it explicitly.

I am completely stranded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does create `onCreate` only three tables?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is just an example. I want to deal with the onUpgrade() method in my application

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, you have certainly found a solution, but I find the question valid (upvoted) and as it did not receive an answer, here are my 2 cents:

Calling `onUpgrade()` from `onCreate()` should work (I did not test it), but there is a better way to organize you helper (see snippet hereafter). The key point is that both those methods are just entry points.

```
public class SampleDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "mydatabase";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

    public SampleDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        updateDatabase(db, 0, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        updateDatabase(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    private void updateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 1) {
            // Create 3 initial tables
        }
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            // Create the new table
        }
    }

}
```

The advantages of this kind of helper:

- You never need to change `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` methods, only `updateDatabase()`.
- For each new version, you just need to :

  - increment DB_VERSION
  - add a new section `if (oldVersion < N) { // do the upgrade }`.

---

Credit : Strongly inspired from [Head First Android Development](https://dogriffiths.github.io/HeadFirstAndroid/), Dawn and David Griffiths, O'Reilly, 2015